# how to simplify/improve an Erlang code?

Tags: refactoring, erlang

How a good Erlang programmer would write this code ?

```
loop(expr0) ->  
    case expr1 of   
    true ->  
       A = case expr2 of  
               true -> ...;  
               false -> ...  
           end;
    false->  
       A = case expr3 of  
               true -> ...;  
               false -> ...  
           end  
  end,  
loop(expr4(A)).
```

Comment: Looks pretty obscure. Could you provide us with some more code? :-)

Comment: Please, format the code with indentation

Comment: `expr0` is not bound. This is not complete snippet.

Comment: Take a look at this question "[Erlang: simple refactoring](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2872954/298282)".

Comment: My insinuation was how to transfrom the code with less "case" and more call to "loop"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to make your code more *readable.* It's usually a good idea extracting bits of code to functions to avoid long or deeply nested functions, and provide self-explained names that clarify the purpose of a piece of code:

```
loop(expr0) ->  
    case expr1 of   
    true ->  
       A = do_something(expr2);
    false->  
       A = do_something_else(expr3)
  end,  
  loop(expr4(A)).

do_something(E) ->
    case E of  
       true -> ...;  
       false -> ...  
    end

do_something_else(E) ->
    case E of  
       true -> ...;  
       false -> ...  
    end
```

Now, a casual reader knows that your function does *something* if expr1 is true and *something else* if expr1 is false. Good naming conventions help a lot here. You can also do that with comments, but code is never outdated, and thus easier to maintain. I also find short functions rather easier to read than really loooong functions. Even if those long functions have coments inlined.

Once you've stated clearly what your function does, you may want to shorten the code. Short code is easier to read and maintain, but don't shorten too much using "clever" constructions, or you'll obscure it, which is the opposite of what you want. You can start by using pattern matching in function heads:

```
loop(expr0) ->  
    case expr1 of   
    true ->  
       A = do_something(expr2);
    false->  
       A = do_something_else(expr3)
  end,  
  loop(expr4(A)).

do_something(true) -> ...;
do_something(false) -> ....

do_something_else(true) -> ...;
do_something_else(false) -> ....
```

Then, you can avoid repeating A in the main function (aside, variables scoped out of nested statements is a feature I always disliked)

```
loop(expr0) ->  
  A = case expr1 of   
        true -> do_something(expr2);
        false-> do_something_else(expr3)
      end,  
  loop(expr4(A)).

do_something(true) -> ...;
do_something(false) -> ....

do_something_else(true) -> ...;
do_something_else(false) -> ....
```

And I think that's it for this piece of code. With more context you can also go for some abstractions to reduce duplicity, but take care when abstracting, if you overdo it you'll also obscure the code again, losing the maintenance benefit you'd expected to get by removing similar code.

Answer (score 3):

The code, as it is currently written, is hard to make simpler. The problem are the `ExprX` entries are unknown, so there is no way to simplify the code without knowing that it is beneficial to do so. If you have a more full example, we will have a much better time at attempting to do an optimization of it.

The concrete problem is that we don't know how `Expr2` and `Expr3` depends on `Expr1` for instance. And we don't know what the purpose of `Expr0` is, and neither about `Expr4`'s dependence other than it uses the returned `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Why need expr0 in loop function?